# Upstream timed out (uWSGI + NGINX + Flask)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, redis, uwsgi

I have the following stack for my application:

1. NGINX (1.4.6)
2. uWSGI (1.9.17.1-debian (64bit))
3. Flask
4. Python 3.4

**The Problem**
After NGINX restart all works well for a period(few minutes). After that period I receive a "504 Gateway Time-out" error.

**NGINX log:**

> *13 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.123.39.44, server:
>   app.fc.com, request: "GET /dashboard/overview HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "app.fc.com", referrer:
>   "http://app.fc.com/dashboard/overview"

**uWSGI log:**

> app.fc.com [pid: 100017|app: 0|req: 103/219] 86.123.39.44 () {44 vars
>   in 859 bytes} [Fri Mar  9 06:24:22 2018] GET /login => generated 245
>   bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 3 headers in 131 bytes (1 switches on
>   core 1)

**My NGINX configuration is:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/fc/website;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name app.fc.com;

        location / {
                sendfile        on;
                client_max_body_size 20M;
                keepalive_timeout  0;

                proxy_connect_timeout   10;
                proxy_send_timeout      15;
                proxy_read_timeout      20;

                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8001;
                #uwsgi_read_timeout 30;
                #uwsgi_send_timeout 30;
                uwsgi_connect_timeout 60;
                uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;
        }
}
```

**My uWSGI configuration is:**

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
socket = :8001
#wsgi-file = /var/www/app.fc.com/reviewApp/wsgi.py
wsgi-file = /var/www/fc/app/wsgi.py
callable = app
processes = 2
threads = 4
chdir = /var/www/fc/app/

pythonpath = /var/www/fc/app/
pythonpath = /var/www/py3/lib/python3.4
virtualenv = /var/www/py3
plugins = python3
```

Usually, the response to my request last under 5 seconds

Comment: Did you check  the `uwsgi` log?

Comment: @heemayl I have added the log from uWSGI

Comment: What if you remove uWSGI from the setup and serve the Flask app directly using NGINX? Just to help find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution**

I have discovered this behavior just on the page where Redis was called. I solved(short time solution) this by adding a new connexion at Redis for each request and setting up a connexion idle timeout in Redis config.

**Other discoveries**

Seems Redis hangs for about 931 seconds after 300 seconds of inactivity(which is the interval after this problem appeared) when the connexion is shared across many uWSGI threads.

Comment: Same issue. i have a problem with beanstalkd connection.